# How to catch AttributeError?

Tags: python

How can I catch AttributeError from this line and print message to the user, let's say "you can't change class="post" "

```
post_start = re.search('<div class="post">', html)
```

I tried with try, except AttributeError, raise, print but it's always returning nothing.
That's what I did:

```
try:
    post_start = re.search('<div class="post">', html)
except AttributeError:
    raise
else:
    print 'you can't change <div class="post">'
```

Comment: Why should that code produce an `AttributeError`? Also, you don't raise another error after catching one. Get rid of your `else:` statement, put the `"you can't..."` after your `except:` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.search()` returns `None` if no position in the string matches the pattern. Check for `None` and raise an exception:

```
post_start = re.search('<div class="post">', html)
if post_start is None:
    raise AttributeError('you can\'t change <div class="post">')
```